# How can I take a screenshot in Google Colab using PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, google-colaboratory

I am looking to take a screenshot of my screen on Google Colab for use in a screen recorded video, but as the the notebook runs in linux, I am not sure if this is possible.

My code from python on my device is below

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox= None)
```

When run on Colab, it returns either `OSError: X connection failed: error 5` or `ImportError: ImageGrab is macOS and Windows only`.

Looking for other options, I first tried `mss.mss()`, which returned `$DISPLAY not set.`.  I tried setting the display in the method and using `os`, and neither of which worked.

I then tried `gtk.gdk`, but I was not able to install and import it properly after trying several methods.

I also tried using `pyautogui`, but after importing I was not able to connect to a display, and was returned either a `DisplayConnectionError` or an `OSError`.

Was there a way to fix any of the errors returned using the methods I listed? Or is there another method that I am not aware of to return the contents of a screen as an image in Colab?

Comment: Could you take a screenshot from your browser/computer?

Comment: if you are using linux, there are nice resources like kazam, take screenshot(comes by default in ubuntu systems), why not use that

Answer (score 2):

First you need to setup a virtual monitor:

```
!pip install gym pyvirtualdisplay > /dev/null 2>&1
!apt-get install -y xvfb python-opengl ffmpeg > /dev/null 2>&1

DISPLAY_WIDTH = 1920  
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 1080

from IPython import display as ipythondisplay
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
display.start()
```

Then install pyscreenshot:

```
!pip install pyscreenshot
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
```

Finally grab the picture:

```
frame = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox= None))
```

In `ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x, y, w, h))` you can specify the size of the screen you want to grab as well.