# Is there a way to take a screen shot in google colab using python?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, screenshot

I tried the previous hours to take a screen shot using python in google colab and didn't manage to get what I wanted properly ...

I tried with :

- PIL (error : ScreenShotError: XGetImage() failed)
- pyautogui (error when importing :XauthError: ~/.Xauthority: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.Xauthority')
- mss and pyscreenshot (no error but the screenshot is full black)

Here is my code for mss :

```
import mss
import mss.tools
import time

with mss.mss() as sct:
    filename = f"ecran_entier.png"
    sct.shot(output=filename)
    print(f"Capture d'écran enregistrée : {filename}")

capture_ecran = cv2.imread('ecran_entier.png')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(capture_ecran)
```

and here is the result :

[image: Result of my code]

If you have any idea I could try let me know,
Not closed to any package or function

Thanks

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? What information are you trying to capture in the image?

Comment: did u tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64672576/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-in-google-colab-using-pil

Comment: Yes absolutely, and i have in return a black image (like the example)

Comment: My ultimate goal is to screenshot a poker table, to identify the cards on the board and in your hand, to evaluate the position and to advice the player (it's a little project, I wont train an AI to beat human at poker lol)
So now I want to take the information on the screen by taking a screenshot and then identify cards